# Bash Color Variable Output

Tags: bash, variables, colors

I've got a variable, let's say `$x` and it holds the value of `website.com`.  I want to be able to call the variable and apply shell color to it like so:

```
echo -e '\033[1;32m$x:\033[0m';
```

The problem is not the color, however, it's how the script it interpretting the output.  So the output I'm getting is:

```
$x:
```

I need the output to obviously be the string in the variable, and not the variable name.  Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `"` instead of `'`.

So it should be: `echo -e "\033[1;32m$x:\033[0m";`

Variables are generally interpolated inside double quotes.

Comment: Cool, just be sure to mark the question as answered after the time limit