# PHP:write color text into text file using php(output show into console mode)

Tags: php

I want to write a file using php,where some text are colored.

example:

operation: save. status:passed //its color green

operation:delete. status:failed //its color red

My code is like:

```
<?php
  $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $txt = "operation: save. status:passed\n";//green color
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  $txt = "operation:delete. status:failed\n";//red color
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: In `txt` files there are no ways to have different colors of text. Use `html` or something else.

Comment: @U-MULDER:)Thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to write "colored text" into a plain text file. That format simply does not support any such feature. A plain text file only supports plain text.

You would have to use another format, something like html markup or rich text to be able to specify a color. Such files can certainly be written in php just like any other file. But you have to use the correct syntax as defined by the target format.

I suggest you create such a file manually (using a text editor or similar). When the outcome suits your expectations then you return to your php code and write exactly *that* content into the opened target file. Note: you have to write the raw content, so the markup, not just plain text.

Comment: output show console mode.so it's possible to use html

Comment: What do you mean by "console mode"? HTML markup certainly does _not_ get rendered in a typical console like in 'terminal emulation' (read: shell), if that is what you mean.

Comment: text file show in console mode(linux terminal).(command: cat abc.txt)

Comment: OK, sure you can show that, but you cannot use html markup then. you'd have to use the terminal escape sequences in that case. For an example take a look at typical bash prompt definitions that often offer colored tokens inside the prompt.

Comment: Google offers endless examples. Here is one: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html  Or this one here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466749/bash-colored-output-with-a-variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68583/discussion-between-sandipon-and-arkascha).

Comment: Waiting for your question in that chat room :-)